# Tablet-compatible vector drawing app for OS X?

Tags: macos, software-rec, tablet, drawing

I got a capacitive stylus so I can use my laptop's trackpad as a graphics tablet. It seems like drawing software such as [SketchBook Express](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sketchbook-express/id404243625?mt=12) works quite well, but it only produces bitmap output. Are there any similar applications that would allow me to export my drawing in a vector format like PDF, and which support pressure-sensitivity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered that the free application [Skitch](http://skitch.com/) supports tablet pen pressure and can output vector graphics, so I've been using this with good success.

Comment: For people in the future, Skitch no longer supports pen pressure and can't output vector images either... I just bought a Wacom tablet thinking Skitch would be perfect (it saves to Evernote automatically), but looks like I need something else.

Comment: The old version of skitch is still available for download and should work fine. Hopefully they'll bring back the functionality later...

Comment: I hadn't realised that. Skitch 1 works nicely for pressure width, but doesn't support Retina displays so it looks pretty horrendous on my MBP. Hopefully they'll bring it in to the new version at some point...

Answer (score 2):

[Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) and [iDraw](http://www.indeeo.com/idraw/) are vector based programs that work on the Mac.  I am unsure how they handle pressure-sensitivity on the trackpad.